# LatexMK incorrectly tries to build files used by minted

Tags: compiling, minted, latexmk

I am using LatexMK from a Makefile with the -use-make option. A really great tool to automatically compile my document while making sure all images are up-to-date.

When trying to compile a document that uses the minted package I get the following errors. Note that, to keep the output concise, the PDF was already built before so there is actually nothing to do. Those errors always appear at the end of the output.

The PDF appears to build correctly, but this makes it very hard to see if there were additional errors, as pdflatex always returns with errors. This is also a problem when running it from an IDE.

```
$ make
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make  report.tex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 10 Nov 2013, version: 4.39.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'report.aex' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "report.aex"'
------------
make[1]: Entering directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'report.aex'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'report.out.pyg' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "report.out.pyg"'
------------
make[1]: Entering directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'report.out.pyg'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'report.pyg' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "report.pyg"'
------------
make[1]: Entering directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'report.pyg'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'report.w18' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "report.w18"'
------------
make[1]: Entering directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'report.w18'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/directory/of/my/tex/file'
Latexmk: All targets (report.pdf) are up-to-date
```

To me it seems that these files don't need to be handled by LatexMK at all. I wonder why it even thinks it requires them to build the PDF.

Comment: We are going to need a lot more detail to even attempt to give an answer, e.g., a minimal example complete with your makefile and source file(s).   Latexmk reports that files 'report.aex' etc do not exist.  So there is probably something in the log file about missing files 'report.aex' etc.  These presumably need to be made, and you've invoked latexmk with its -use-make option, so it invokes make to make them.  This is all expected behavior.